# Matching entities with ManyToMany relationship with any element of a Set

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

In JPA/JQL, I've as input a `Set<Tag>` and I want to find entities that are associated to at least one Tag in my input Set (`:tags`).

The `Tagged` entity has a property tags

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<Tag> tags;
```

How the query should look like? I've tried

`SELECT t FROM Tagged t WHERE t.tags = ANY(:tags)`

but it's not correct. Does anyone know how the correct query should be?

**Example**: if a Tagged Entity has Tags `("one", "two", "tree")` and my `:tags` input parameter is a Set of Tags `("three", "four")`, I expect a match because `"three"` is in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `ANY(subquery)` is what you're looking for. I would use an [inner join](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_inner_joins) instead. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t FROM Tagged t JOIN t.tags tag WHERE tag IN :tags
```